How to handle Staging Ground comments that are helpful to answering the question
I encountered a comment on this Staging Ground post which is not about improving the question, but rather, potentially helpful in solving the problem:

400 means Bad Request, and the request is bad. You're trying to set the content type header both in the content and HttpClient. I have no idea what that will produce. You don't need to manually serialize to JSON the bytes either, use JsonContent with an actual object, not strings, and let that serialize the object and generate the correct headers

When the post graduated out of Staging Ground, the comment is no longer there, which makes sense because the expectation is for Staging Ground comments to be about improving the question, not answering it (at least, I think it is?).
Is there a way to handle this scenario by either educating the person who left the comment so they understand it will not be retained, or migrating answer-related comments to the graduated question?

I don't know if there is any path to getting in touch with the commenter at this point. In this specific case, there isn't enough meat on that comment to migrate it to an answer and if answer-as-comment is the most appropriate solution, the question has flaws that need addressing before promotion-for example it's a typo or a duplicate that needs a wee bit of additional explanation.

I don't think the question is both answerable and useful for others in its current state. It basically just say "I get an error". That's it. Then we're supposed to guess what the error is and what to do about it. How would somebody find out they have the same problem? The commenter covers part of that. And then shotguns "try using more standard practices". That's not really a solution. It's probably sound advice but what does it solve? The critique is that a lot of the operations are done by hand for no good reason. IMO, this should have been marked as requiring major changes.

See also: Should I comment possible solutions in SG when the question can't be published yet.

@VLAZ - Perhaps I'm not clear on the standard for promoting out of Staging Ground. I assumed the standard was that the question was good enough that it wouldn't be something I'd flag to close if it were a non-SG question. Not that the question had no further room for improvement. I promoted it b/c I saw enough info in the code segment to at least give a chance that someone can answer it (b/c it's an error code 400, which means there's a problem with the request itself) . I'm now understanding, through your comment and others', that I should raise the bar on the standard I'm using. TY.

I already voted it to be closed. Because I don't believe there is enough information to be answered. A few comments on the published question also ask for more information. And the only answer there is yet another "try to use standard practices" shotgun shot in the dark. Actually a bit more - it's "here is some code. Write your own code based on it"

This is not what Staging Ground is made for. The objective is not to try to find an answer, but only try to have a nice question before posting it. So, this comment seems partially off-topic/not necessary now.
What the commenter should do?
Firstly, they should check if the question is answerable, which is not the case for me as it seems there is some missing debugging information and logs.
Then, ONLY IF the question is good, they should accept the question to be published. THEN, when the question is published, post a comment or an answer.
What you can do as other reviewer?
You can do multiple things:

Post their comment and mention it's not your own comment, like "The text of comment" - @Someone (from [Staging Ground](link)).
If post isn't accepted yet, reply to their comment and say it's not the right place
Leave it alone and hope the OP sees the comment, and will take it in count
If the comment is trying to explain basic things, try to find another question that could be a duplicate (which could also be the case here)


"The objective is not to try to find an answer" yeah but being nice trumps protocol every time. It is a wickedly interesting and difficult problem to solve; how do you make people contain themselves and follow protocol. Step 1: make sure the protocol is clear. I don't think we're there yet.

@Gimby Yes, but you can stay nice and follow the protocol. Also, if you post a complete answer with good explaination, it's better than posting a comment that say global informations. An answer is also rewarding for both OP and answerer, even more than a simple comment

IMHO part of the problem is that they're really reviews that pretend to be questions, scattered between regular posts. If you intentionally confuse people, then it shouldn't be a surprise when they actually are confused.

@Gimby Yes, that's why I proposed way that doesn't require other user approval. Also, with "people don't ignore this" we can ignore almost all post, for me it's not a good argument
