Keep references to SG question/comments in a published question
This is a scenario I already witnessed a dozen times despite the young age of Staging Ground:

the users leave constructive comments in a proposed question
the OP isn't responsive enough and misses or ignores them
a proposed question is published with no or not enough improvement
a published question contains no reference to prior work and starts getting similar comments or close/downvotes

The solutions aren't supposed to be posted to SG, but the comments can contain useful information that will lead to the solutions, it shouldn't be lost.
Currently I have to deduce that the uncommented question, which I recall seeing with some comments, is the published one. Then I find the proposed one from SG in browser history, post a link to it and/or denote the issues that were already discussed. The comments that need formatting need to be formatted again when pasting them.
This makes SG much less useful than it could be. Part of the problem is that the quality of the reviews could be better, but I'm sure that at the point where only improved SG questions can leave, it will become a graveyard of questions, the users will just avoid it at all. So at least allowing to the OP and other users to start where they finished after publishing could improve the process.
A quick and effective solution would be to auto-add a link to SG question as the first comment. It would be valuable to have an option to show or repost the comments from SG.

"a proposed question is published with no or not enough improvement" - Then it should probably not have been published.

A question like that should not have been posted. All necessary information need to be edited into the question prior to it leaving SG

Also note that the Staging Ground question is accessible as a link in the timeline.

When users who aren't moderators post comments that aren't about improving the question, I usually replay with a reminder that they're in the Staging Ground with a link to https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/431022/238704

@Dharman But this happens any way and currently there's no way to revert or prevent this. The supposed way to handle this is to close a bad question and inform the OP that they need to go through SG again, is that correct? But a lot of times a published question isn't worse than an average one that doesn't end up closed. It's just not good enough to be answered and needs MRE or some kind of improvement that have been already discussed in comments at SG, hence the concern

Once a question is on the main site, it's on the main site and should be handled as a normal (non-Staging Ground) question. If there is important information from the Staging Ground, you can add that via comments. I doubt closing the question in favor of the OP asking a new one going through the Staging Ground being a good idea.

@dan1st Can you clarify re the timeline, do you mean this? https://stackoverflow.com/posts/79141669/revisions It mentions SG but with no link, and  revisions don't seem to be available as a link in a question with no edits

@EstusFlask I am talking about https://stackoverflow.com/posts/79141669/timeline which can be accessed using the clock/rounded arrow symbol below the voting and bookmark buttons. The bottom-most entry (or maybe second entry in some special cases) should be a link to the Staging Ground post.

When the question got published and then closed, then what's done is done. Just tell OP once more what info needs to be edited into the question to get it reopened. They DO NOT need to repost the question to go through SG again.

If the question lacks MRE or some other critical information then it should not have been posted from SG. I know that it happens and when it does we proceed as normal. Just close the question and await the information from OP as if it had been posted on the main site without SG.

Also I want to mention that copying SG comments to the main site question or similar would likely do more damage than good. Most of these comments are obsolete when the question is posted.

Either way, whatever happened in SG is irrelevant now. If the question still lacks detail then it's a fail on the SG reviewers.

Just to point it out again: DO NOT TELL OP TO POST THE QUESTION AGAIN. This is against the site rules and they will suffer the consequences. The reposted question will be deleted anyway.


a proposed question is published with no or not enough improvement

This is where the process went wrong.

a published question contains no reference to prior work and starts getting similar comments or close/downvotes

This is deliberate, because the entire premise of the Staging Ground is that there is supposed to have been "enough improvement" by the time the question is published (and of course there's no automated way to check that - and we don't want attempts at such).
Users who publish questions inappropriately need to be educated, which is why there is an effort in progress.

but the comments can contain useful information that will lead to the solutions, it shouldn't be lost.

"Useful information" really falls into two categories:

Things that help the OP to do debugging, in order to figure out what the problem actually is. Once this has been done and the question is in proper shape, there is no longer a value to these comments.

Things intended to help OP personally solve a problem, out of pity or to be charitable, specifically because the question is not suitable. For example, if the problem was due to a typo, it could be "useful information" to point out the typo; if the question needs more focus because OP has a problem that breaks down into following a series of steps, "useful information" could identify what the steps are. But if the question was due to a typo then it shouldn't be published, and if it needs more focus then the appropriate version of the question will focus on a single step, and then the breakdown of the larger problem is no longer relevant.


In really all cases, information that is useful in the SG is not actually useful to answering a suitable question.

Currently I have to deduce that the uncommented question, which I recall seeing with some comments, is the published one.

I don't quite understand what you're trying to say. The Staging Ground UI is quite different from the main site UI.

Then I find the proposed one from SG in browser history

Please don't repost those comments without a good, clearly thought out reason specific to that question. They usually just don't have the value you think they do. In general, there are way too many comments remaining on the main site.

I'm sure that at the point where only improved SG questions can leave, it will become a graveyard of questions

Increasing the number of total questions on the site is not the goal. "A graveyard of questions" is fine as long as there really aren't any more good questions left to ask.

A quick and effective solution would be to auto-add a link to SG question as the first comment.

When a question is published from the Staging Ground, the timeline for the main site version will link back to the original. Click the clock icon below the voting UI for the question, and select the first "Created from Staging Ground" entry on the subsequent page (the URL should look like https://stackoverflow.com/posts/<question_id>/timeline).


but the comments can contain useful information that will lead to the solutions, it shouldn't be lost

Answer material goes in answers. If they want to answer, they can follow the SG item and post an answer once it's pubished.
If it's not answer material and is info that should lead to question improvement, then it should lead to question improvement. Unfortunately, once an item leaves SG, it has left SG.

a published question contains no reference to prior work

Not entirely true. Post history should link to SG item.

at the point where only improved SG questions can leave, it will become a graveyard of questions, the users will just avoid it at all. So at least allowing to the OP and other users to start where they finished after publishing could improve the process.

Items stale in major/minor changes leave review listing and are not published. Items stale pending re-review get autopublished. So if there are comments in SG doing what SG is for- soliciting improvement to a question, and reviewers properly send the ball to the asker's court, and no reviewer prematurely approves publishing, then no review comments will be "lost" or "wasted".

"Items stale where the ball is in the asker's court leave review listing and are not published. Items stale with ball in reviewer's court get autopublished." Sorry, I didn't follow that at all.

@KarlKnetchel If the next action is up to the asker (major/minor changes), the question doesn't graduate. If the next action is up to the reviewers (new post, requested reevaluation), the question automatically graduates after a set time.
